# Is there a java library or open source to translate Chinese to English as it is pronounced?

Tags: translate

I'd like to translate Chinese to English as it is pronounced only.
The Chinese could be person name, company name and so on.

Below is an example.
江婧敬 => Jiang Jingjing

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:
sorry I overlooked 'java library'. Here's a similar library in Java: [pinyin4j](http://pinyin4j.sourceforge.net/)

Try using Chinese->pinyin tools, like [this python tool](https://github.com/lxyu/pinyin) (not tried myself)